# Problem with partial views and tinymce

Tags: codeigniter, tinymce

In a view (master view) another view is called with $this->load->view(‘sub_view’);
In the sub_view i have a textarea to use with tinymce.

If I combine the views in one single view and call it from my controller my js works fine and the textarea converts to tinymce editor.

If i use the master - sub scenario and my js targets elements in the sub_view although the same html is returned to the browser js doesn’t fire up correctly and instead of my textarea the whole div that is contained in the sub_view is converted to tinymce. It's like if the contents are loaded afterwards or something.

By the way if i setup just an onclick=alert"()" in the subview it fires up.

Edit: You can grab an example from codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/179792

Comment: code please... give us the controller and both views

Comment: you can grab an example from 
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/179792/ 

Thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 0):

Figured it all out.
It had nothing to do with either codeigniter or tinymce
It was markup error
in the main view there was a  and the textarea id was also content.

I don't know why it worked correct in full_view 
In the init it was 'textarea.tinymce' and textarea had class='tinymce' while the div had the same id too but was not a textarea.

but in the sub_view the wrong markup caused errors.
Changing ids fixed it
Thanks anyone for taking time to review the problem.